Using htaccess to rewrite an encoded question mark %3F to a non-encoded question mark?
Opening this link on my server:
https://www.example.com/url-thumbs?url=https%3A%2F%2Fmoodle.example.com%2Fcourse%2Fview.php%3Fid%3D369
Apache gives: Forbidden You don't have permission to access this URL.
Replacing the %3F with a question mark character would load the site. The %3F is an encoded question mark.
The htaccess contains:
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# For Friendly URLs
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]

But this should be irrelevant.
I tried to use inside the following directive with .htaccess:
# Decode the %3F to ?
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)%3F(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1$2 [L,NE]

But it does not work. Still "Forbidden" showing up in the server.
Update:
I checked file /srv/users/SYSUSER/log/APPNAME/APPNAME_apache.error.log. It states:
[rewrite:error]
AH10508: Unsafe URL with %3f URL rewritten without UnsafeAllow3F

And this leads to: 403 Forbidden when URL contains GET with encoded question mark / UnsafeAllow3F / rawurlencode
I ended up rewriting the URL with PHP:
// encode URL for thumbnail generation
$url_out = urlencode($url);
                
// if the line_url contains a question mark, then Apache does not allow the encoded %3F
$url_out = str_replace('%3F', '?', $url_out);

